# Why does a lead compensator with little phase contribution reduce the overshoot of the system so dramatically

Tags: control-engineering, control-theory

I am currently designing a lead compensator to allow the following system to conform to some specific requirements: $$ G(s)=\frac{2}{s(s+2)(s+5)} $$

When using the angle criteria to meet these requirements, I find that the resulting step response struggles to meet the requirements without some further iteration. I believe this is due to the system being third-order and the equations for overshoot and settling time being based on second-order systems.

However, in addition to the lead compensator designed using the above methods, I have found that placing a zero and a pole either side of the least dominant pole of the system (at -5) fixes all of these issues and has quite a large impact on correcting the system to meet the overshoot and settling time requirements.

I can't seem to explain why this would be the case as it only adds about half the amount of phase as the other lead compensator adds to the system, yet seems to impact the system so much more than having two of the same high-phase lead compensators in series.

Any guidance as to why this would be the case would be hugely appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your help!

John.

Comment: Can you show the compensator you have using the angle criteria?

Comment: Anyway, best way to get insight is to do root locus plots. be sure to use same scale when comparing plots

Comment: You can also look at this using bode analysis, it's a perfect example for it. It can sortof tell you the same story in a different way, which is "given my poles and zeros, including both the plant and controller, how much gain can I add before i get in trouble" (with more gain typically resulting in higher bandwidth)

Comment: Suppose you block after you get hit... Now change the timing to actually block the hit. Dramatic difference?

Comment: oh and another consideration, that won't show up in RL analysis -- zeros in the passband will lead to overshoot